# Joomla 3.2: Styling the Footer (divs next to each other)

Tags: css, html, joomla

I'm trying to style the footer of a website made using Joomla 3.2.

Here's a picture of it:

(http://imageshack.com/a/img585/9589/1edo.png)

I renamed the classes so I can modify it with CSS but the problem is that I can't put the div(s) next to each other!

Here's the HTML:

```
<footer class="row-fluid">

      <div class="footer1">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer1" style="html5" />
            <h3>Main Links:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www...">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www...">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www...">Company Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www...">Company Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www...">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www...">Site Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="footer2">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer2" style="html5" />
            <h3>Contact Us:</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Address: 28 ...</li>
          <li>Phone: 0224</li>
          <li>Email: ...@....com</li>
          <li>Mobile: 0100</li>
          <li>Fax: </li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="footer3">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer3" style="html5" />
            <div class="span4"><img src="templates/greensand/images/footerlogo.png" alt="Greensand, Inc." class="pull-right" /></div>

      </div>            


       <div class="footer4">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer4" style="html5" />
         <p>&copy; 2014 Greensand, Inc. All rights reserved. </p>

      </div>

</footer>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
footer .span9 { 
    padding: 4em 0 0 3em; 
    clear: both; 
} 

footer p { 
    padding-left: 0em; text-align: center; 
} 

footer .nav-pills a { 
    color: #fff; 
} 

footer .nav-pills a:hover { 
    color: #21AB49; 
} 

.footer1 { 
    padding-left: 3em; 
}
```

*Does anyone have any ideas to make them sit next to each other with a white line between them?*

> Main Links | Contact Us | the Logo and at the bottom the copyright

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: not much just float to left and other codes that doesn't work!! :))

Comment: Your CSS doesn't have any styles related to the list you want to change.  In fact, you CSS targets `.nav-pills` and that class isn't even in the HTML.

Comment: @davidpauljunior Maybe the module rendered the .nav-pills inside the footer.

Comment: @MohamedSherif Can you just paste the HTML source of Footer section ?

Comment: @MohamedSherif Your question is about HTML and CSS so you should show the outputted HTML.

Comment: first thanks for the response .. i tried to add styles to footer2 and 3 and also 4 and none works .. i just want them at the same line and the copyright at the bottom of the page .. how can i do that

Comment: @Jobin .. i already posted the HTML code of the footer?

Comment: @MohamedSherif what about footer module rendering output?

Comment: @JobinJose: so sorry but i guess i've no idea what you are talking about! .. did u mean a photo of the footer or something?

Comment: @MohamedSherif Oh my friend! In your CSS you're using like footer .span9  and footer .nav-pills but those span9 or nav-pills are not in your HTML code you pasted. I guess those class html section rendered through module Then only we can say how you can write Css according to that is that clear ? In other words go to page source and copy your footer section and paste it.

Comment: @JobinJose: got it now .. i already deleted the .span9 it was for the copyright styling and now after i renamed the classes it doesn't exist now